# Button under RecyclerView in BottomSheetDialogFragment is not showing properly (when STATE_COLLAPSED)

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have fragment inherited of BottomSheetDialogFragment.
It's layout is ConstraintLayout and consist of:

- TextView (header)
- RecyclerView (list of my addresses)
- LinearLayout (image + editText for add new address)
- Button (confirmation of choice)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
  android:padding="14dp"
  app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="My addresses"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/addNewAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    tools:listitem="@layout/address_delivery_item" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addNewAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addNewAddressButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_button"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addNewEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:hint="Add new address"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Button.Contained"
    android:background="@drawable/app_confirm_button"
    android:text="SELECT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

My expectation is to show fragment with height by **content** + **field for new address** + **button** in both behavior state (STATE_COLLAPSED and STATE_EXPANDED)

When I open this fragment in STATE_EXPANDED behavior, all shows correct:
[screenshot STATE_EXPANDED behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k0Sq.png)

When I open this fragment in STATE_COLLAPSED behavior,button and editText doesn't appear: [screenshot STATE_COLLAPSED behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZhh4.png)

I tried to bind and unbind RecyclerView to LinearLayout(id/addNewAddress) but in doesn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this behavior? to make the button appear in STATE_COLLAPSED?

I will be very grateful for the help!

Comment: Try by setting recycler view height to android:layout_height="0dp"